# Are jaxrs 1.1 (WLP 8.5) annotated methods thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, web-services, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

I am using jaxrs1.1 jar shipped with Websphere liberty profile 8.5 for creating REST WebService.

Lets suppose we have a method addNewProject as shown below :

If many people call this webservice method to add project concurrently. using link below , are there any concurrency issue? In servlet, each request is a separate thread , is it the same case here or should we handle concurrency by ourselves ?

endpointLink: http://somehost.com/path1/path2/addprojectdetails and POST the JSON object.

```
@POST   
@Path("addprojectdetails")   
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public Response addNewProject(ProjectDetails projectdetailsObj) {  
return Response.status(200).entity("Project"+projectdetailsObj.getProjectname()+"successfully added").build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of concurrency issues you might be thinking of.  The object itself can be either a singleton or request scoped (if using CDI) or a stateless session bean (if using EJB).  If you're using a singleton, then you may need to be thread aware and not store state within the class.

It would probably help to understand what kind of concurrency issues you had in mind to answer more thoroughly.

Comment: "and not store state within the class." -> Answered my question . Thx !